# trouble getting the sum of rows of a particular ID in DataTable

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

[image]

i have an sql query like this :

```
 string PendingMsgsQuery = "select FROM_CLIENT,CHAT_MSG from chat where TO_CLIENT=" + clientID + " and CHAT_STATUS='p' ";
```

and a DataTable like in the image wish it get it's value from the result return by this query the 'FROM_CLient' is not static it may vary depending on the 'TO_CLIENT' value

my question is :
i want to return the id of the From_CLient and the Count of the CHAT_MSG for that client how can i do that is there any particular solution to do this ?

Comment: And by `sum` you mean concatenation, right?

Comment: Have you mentioned the word `DataTable` as replacement for the result of your query or with regard to the same-named class in .NET which is used for in-memory data?

Comment: Can we see a simple ERD of the table/tables used

Comment: i meant Count not sum sorry and By DataTable i meant the result of my query is stored in a DataTable that have the same schema of this Table

Comment: You're (potentially) open to SQL Injection - you should be using parameterized queries.  Also, you probably shouldn't be storing encoded spaces that way, especially if they're line-ending.  If they're actually important, I'd potentially store them as the unicode/UTF-8 versions, not the HTML/SGML versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `group by` query, grouping by `FROM_CLIENT`

```
 string PendingMsgsQuery = "select FROM_CLIENT, count(0) as QUANTITY from chat where TO_CLIENT=" + clientID + " and CHAT_STATUS='p' group by FROM_CLIENT ";
```

Comment: +1 - `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(CHAR_MSG)`, maybe, if profiling shows that helps) is more often used, but what you've got should work.